# clearQueue in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery script that takes an img src, puts the src in hidden div, and enlarge the img with animation when hover the request img. However, when I jump from img to img the `clearQueue` or `stop` are not working as needed.

In this sample when I jump slowly from img to another img it works ok, but when I jump fast the img is fadeout totally more and more between img to img.

All I want is to be able to hover fast or slow from img to img and there will be no Queue that left behind.

I will be glad if someone can help me with this.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".thumb").hover(function(e) {
        $('#popm').css('left',e.pageX+50);
        $('#popm').css('top', e.pageY+50);
        e.preventDefault();
        var src= $(this).attr("src");
        $('.popimg').attr({"src": src});
        $('#popm').stop().fadeIn(100);
        $('.popimg').stop()
            .animate({
                width: '145px', /* Set new width */
                height: '145px' /* Set new height */
            }, 200);
    }, function() {
        $('#popm').stop().fadeOut(100);
        $('.popimg').stop()
            .animate({          
                width: '45px', /* Set new width */
                height: '45px' /* Set new height */ 
        }, 200);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to do `.stop(true, true)` instead of just `.stop()`.

Documentation for [jQuery.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) clearly states that stop has two parameters of which first is a boolean to clear animation queue:

> .stop( [clearQueue,] [jumpToEnd] )
>
> clearQueue - A Boolean indicating whether to remove queued animation as well. Defaults to false.
>
> jumpToEnd - A Boolean indicating whether to complete the current animation immediately. Defaults to false.